# selectOneMenu Converter

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, selectonemenu

Hi every body I'm working on Primfaces pages and I have to make a selectOneMenu wich get items from dataBase so I tried to make it this way but I still have problem's with the converter

so my source Codes are the folowing :

selectOneMenu :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="devises" required="true" value="#{pret.devise}" effect="fade" converter="devise">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{devise.listDevise()}" var="devise" itemLabel="#{devise.nomDevise}" itemValue="#{devise}"/>  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

converter code:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "devise")
public class DeviseConverter implements Converter{  

    public static List<Devise> devises = Devise.listDevise();  

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {  
        if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {  
            return null;  
        } else {  
            try {  
                int idDevise = Integer.parseInt(submittedValue);
                for (Devise p : devises) {  
                    if (p.getIdDevise()== idDevise) {  
                        return p;  
                    }  
                }
            } catch(NumberFormatException exception) {  
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid Devise"));  
            }  
        }
        return null;  
    }  

    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {  
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {  
            return "";  
        } else {  
            return String.valueOf(((Devise) value).getIdDevise());  
        }  
    }
}
```

the error Code is : "devises: Validation Error: Value is not valid"

Comment: Do you have equals() and hashCode() methods in your bean?

Answer (score 0):

Your object `Devise` would need to contain `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Also you can use this `generic converter` which would workd for all the types of object and you won't need to write a converter for all the select lists.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
        for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```